# Amana Gas Dryer Stops Heating After a Minute

Tags: dryer

I have a problem with my Amana gas dryer (model# NGD7200TW). After 15 years, my dryer has the following issue. The dryer turns on and heats up for about 1-2 minutes, and then the heat shuts off but the drum still rotates. If I turn off the dryer and wait about ten minutes and turn it back on the heat will turn on again for about 1-2 minutes then shuts off.

I’ve checked the venting and it’s fine. Any suggestions as to what to investigate? Since the heat turns on (at least or a few minutes), I’m wondering if it’s more like a problem with one of the thermostats or an issue with the gas valve coil.

**UPDATE: I replaced the High Limit Thermostat but the same problem. When the dryer is started from a cold state the ignitor fires up and the heat turns on. After about 2 minutes the heat shuts off but the ignitor will cycle (glow) every few minutes but no heat.**

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Likely a sensor or thermostat or overheat switch (which is similar to a thermostat, but indicates something wrong with the venting or burner, so the dryer is getting too hot. Typically a safety switch beyond any thermostat.

Comment: Have you gone looking for the user's manual for that model? They may include some debugging flowcharts that cover the more common failure cases.

Answer (score 1):

`If I turn off the dryer and wait about ten minutes and turn it back on the heat will turn on again for about 1-2 minutes then shuts off.` would indicate it is a heat sensor. First give the dryer a full clean to remove all and any lint.

It has an overheat sensor to protect it from over heating, so it is just protecting its self.

Find and look in the instructions manual in case you need to replace that sensor.

I found this for your model [Limit switch](https://www.partselect.com/PS11741822-Whirlpool-WP35001092-High-Limit-Thermostat.htm?SourceCode=21&SearchTerm=NGD7200TW10&ModelNum=NGD7200TW10)

`High Limit Thermostat Specifications This high limit thermostat controls the level of heat in a dryer to prevent overheating. It does this by measuring the temperature inside of the dryer drum and turns off when it reaches 260 degrees Fahrenheit. It turns back on once the temperature drops to 210 degrees Fahrenheit`

Another component that is responsible for keeping the flame on (when requested) is the **Flame Sensor** Flame sensor as it name says, is responsible to report that the flame is ON. If not the system will try few time to Ignite and then shut down the gas flow for safety reason.

That part looks like this:

[sensor](https://www.partselect.com/PS11741429-Whirlpool-WP338906-Dryer-Radiant-Flame-Sensor.htm?SourceCode=19&SearchTerm=NGD7200TW10&ModelNum=NGD7200TW10)

Comment: I replaced the High Limit Thermostat but the same problem. When the dryer is started from a cold state the ignitor fires up and the heat turns on. After about 2 minutes the heat shuts off but the ignitor will cycle (glow) every few minutes but no heat.

Comment: check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_wzzcN2J9o&t=95s

Comment: You might need to replace this part https://www.partselect.com/PS11741429-Whirlpool-WP338906-Dryer-Radiant-Flame-Sensor.htm?SourceCode=19&SearchTerm=NGD7200TW10&ModelNum=NGD7200TW10

Comment: Even in comments, it would be helpful to indicate what that part is for when the vendor rearranges their site and that link is no longer valid. Also, it's always better to include that info in your answer since comments can get deleted.

Comment: That would be a **flame sensor**, as per usual.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** I replaced the Gas Valve Solenoids and that solved the dryer heat problem. It was a toss up between a faulty High Limit Thermostat (which I replaced first) and the Gas Valve Solenoid. I should have bought both parts right away as they were so cheap (less that $20 total on Amazon). Saved myself over $200 by doing it myself. The hardest part was taking apart the dryer without breaking anything (I did break a single plastic clip).  Want to thank everyone for the suggestions.

[image]
[image: Gas Valve Solenoid]